# Excel VBA - Add LEFT Formula and Sort A to Z

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a VBA code to re-arrange the column from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 in a particular format

Now when VBA code is run it populates the data correctly in Sheet 2 in Columns A to E and Column G

I want to add a Formula in Column F where it should return certain data from Column B

**Formula for Column F: "=LEFT(RIGHT(B2,10),9)**

This formula should be executed until last blank row

Secondly, I would like to arrange this Sheet 2 alphabetically (a to z) based on column A

My VBA Code is:

```
Sub ModdedMap()

Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet, Sh3 As Worksheet
Dim HeadersOne As Range, HeadersTwo As Range
Dim hCell As Range

With ThisWorkbook
    Set Sh1 = .Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Sh2 = .Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set Sh3 = .Sheets("Sheet3")
End With

Set HeadersOne = Sh3.Range("A1:A" & Sh3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each hCell In HeadersOne

    SCol = GetColMatched(Sh1, hCell.Value)
    TCol = GetColMatched(Sh2, hCell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
    LRow = GetLastRowMatched(Sh1, hCell.Value)
    
    For Iter = 2 To LRow
        Sh2.Cells(Iter, TCol).Value = Sh1.Cells(Iter, SCol).Value
    Next Iter
    
Next hCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetLastRowMatched(Sh As Worksheet, Header As String) As Long
    ColIndex = Application.Match(Header, Sh.Rows(1), 0)
    GetLastRowMatched = Sh.Cells(Rows.Count, ColIndex).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Function GetColMatched(Sh As Worksheet, Header As String) As Long
    ColIndex = Application.Match(Header, Sh.Rows(1), 0)
    GetColMatched = ColIndex
End Function
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: column **F** of which worksheet ??

Comment: Column F of Sheet 2